# Why can't I get s=ON on my MyTouch 4g?

Tags: adb, unrooting

I have followed the following 2 tutorials on how to unroot and get S=ON on the MyTouch 4g:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=834225

I have successfully reverted to the stock ROM and unrooted the phone, but I still have S=OFF.  When I run the first one in the emulator, it gets all the way through execution and tells me to reboot into hboot to get s=ON, but when I do that, it still shows S=OFF:

```
Duplicating hboot
2048+0 records in
2048+0 records out
1048576 bytes transferred in 0.563 secs (1862479 bytes/sec)
Synchronizing
Powerdown and reboot into hboot to check s=on
```

I really would like to get S=ON so that I can ask my provider for service if I need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, my problem was that I have unrooted my phone before attempting to reset to S=Off.  The kernel Did not allow this, because the phone was, obviously, not rooted.  After rerooting my phone and attempting the method above again (I had to enter the commands in the unroot script manually.  It didnt work when just running the script), I was able to get S=On and revert to the Stock ROM.

Answer (score 1):

This link should help. It contains a link to a thread detailing a special zip file created by one of the developers. It will help you possibly get S-ON. The step by step instructions are in the thread:

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=863899

By the way, S-OFF isn't something service technicians actively look for. Many people have sent in phones for servicing with S-Off and technicians still fix it. With my Nexus One, once you get S-Off, it shows an unlock symbol that doesn't go away and is shown every time with the splash image during boot. However, many of my friends with this phone have gotten it fixed without problems.

EDIT: If the S-OFF doesnt work, you should private message or PM the developer who created the zip file on xda. He will be better able to help you as he has repeatedly got S-ON and S-OFF. I dont have the same device. Unfortunately, the bootloaders are device specific and vary on the manufacturer. My experience with S-OFF will be different from yours.

Comment: I have attempted that and I still have S=OFF.  If you don't mind me asking, what provider do you have?  I have brought my phone in before and the salespeople seem to check for S=Off before they will even process a claim, which I assume means that they will void my warranty if the see S=Off, as I have been told before.

Comment: @Gautham: Sending people to some other site for their answer isn't really helpful. Linkrot happens, of course. Can you at least summarize what will be found at that destination?

Comment: @AlEverett, you are right. Edited the post according to your recommendation.

Comment: @ewok My service provider is T-Mobile but they aren't the ones who repair it. It usually is sent to a manufacturer's service center (GSM based phones anyway) so mine would go to an HTC repair center.